# Passing pointers and allocating memory results in segfault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm writing a C program, but I'm having a little trouble with pointers and allocating memory the right way. Here's my code:

```
void read_file(char* file_name, float***** data, unsigned char**** flagged, 
              unsigned char**** initial_flagged)
{
  int nr_stations;
  int nr_times;
  int nr_subbands;
  int nr_subbands_in_file;
  int nr_channels;
  int nr_polarizations;
  int i,j,k;
  int err;

  /*Unnecessary code omitted*/


 //allocate memory for data and flags.

  *data = (float****) malloc(sizeof(float***) * nr_times);
  if(*data == NULL){
    perror("Error allocating memory for data buffer:");
    exit(1);
  }
  *flagged = (unsigned char***) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char **) * nr_times);
  if(*flagged == NULL){

    perror("Error allocating memory for flag buffer:");
    exit(1);
  }
  *initial_flagged = (unsigned char***) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char **) * nr_times);
  if(*initial_flagged == NULL){
    perror("Error allocating memory for flag buffer:");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(i=0;i<nr_times;i++){
    *data[i] = (float ***) malloc(sizeof(float**) * nr_subbands);
    if(*data[i] == NULL){
      perror("Error allocating memory for data on time");
      exit(1);
    }
    *flagged[i] = (unsigned char **) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *) * nr_subbands);
    if(*flagged[i] == NULL){
      perror("Error allocating memory for flags on time");
      exit(1);
    }
    *initial_flagged[i] = (unsigned char **) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *) 
    * nr_subbands);
    if(*initial_flagged[i] == NULL){
      perror("Error allocating memory for initial_flags on time");
      exit(1);
    }

    for(j=0;j<nr_subbands;j++){
      *data[i][j] = (float **) malloc(sizeof(float*) * nr_polarizations);
      if(*data[i][j] == NULL){
        perror("Error allocating memory for data on subband at time");
        exit(1);
      }

      for(k=0;k<nr_polarizations;k++){
        *data[i][j][k] = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * nr_channels);
        if(*data[i][j][k] == NULL){
          perror("Error allocating memory for data on on polarization on subband at time ");
          exit(1);
        }
        memset(*data[i][j][k], 0, sizeof(float) * nr_channels);
      }
      *flagged[i][j] = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * nr_channels);
      if(*flagged[i][j] == NULL){
        perror("Error allocating memory for flags on subband at time");
        exit(1);
      }
      *initial_flagged[i][j] = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) *
      nr_channels);
      if(*initial_flagged[i][j] == NULL){
        perror("Error allocating memory for initial flags on subband at time");
        exit(1);
      }
      memset(*flagged[i][j], 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * nr_channels);
      memset(*initial_flagged[i][j], 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * nr_channels);
    }
  }

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  float**** data = NULL;
  unsigned char*** flagged = NULL;
  unsigned char*** initial_flagged = NULL;

  if(argc != 2){
    printf("Usage: flagger <filename>\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  read_file(argv[1], &data, &flagged, &initial_flagged); 
  printf("data = %p\n", data);
  return 0;


}
```

When I run this code, it segfaults at

> *data[i][j][k] = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * nr_channels);

However, when I don't pass the pointers to data, flagged or initial_flagged to the method but declare them within the scope of the function this works fine, but I can't use these arrays outside of the function.

Comment: `float*****`, that's the first time I see five stars.

Comment: @YuHao Any better ways of passing around four-dimensional arrays? :)

Comment: @Linus common sense,`structs`, `typedef`, using one dimensional array with better indexing, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the dereference operator (ie *) has a lower level or priority than the array subscripting operators (ie []).

Therefore, the operation `*data[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(data[i][j])`. In your program, it led to a segfault because it was interpreting the value at `data[i][j]` as an address, and was trying to access the data stored at this address, while it was actually a float.

So, in this case, you HAVE to use parenthesis, like `(*data)[i][j]`.

See [C/C++ Operator Predecence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've figured it out myself (rubber duck debugging I guess). 
Apparently there is a difference between *data[i][j] and (*data)[i][j]. The second one is what I meant, and makes my code run correctly!